# how to pass pointer to member function of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, function-pointers

I just faced an interesting challenge, let's solve it together:

I had a Broker class similar to this:

```
//Broker.h
#pragma once
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
template<class AGENT_MSG_TYPE,class BUFFER_MSG_TYPE>
class Broker
{
public:
    void messageReceiveCallback(boost::shared_ptr<ConnectionHandler>cnnHadler , std::string message){}

};
```

and a connection handler like this:

```
//ConnectionHandler.h
#pragma once
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <iostream>

//connection handler
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object, ptrToMember) ((object).*(ptrToMember))

template<class A,class B>
class Broker;

class ConnectionHandler: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<ConnectionHandler>
{
    typedef void (Broker<int,int>::*messageReceiveCallback)(boost::shared_ptr<ConnectionHandler>,std::string);
    messageReceiveCallback receiveCallBack;
    Broker<int,int> &theBroker;
public:

    ConnectionHandler(
            //...
            Broker<int,int>& broker,
            messageReceiveCallback callback
            //,...
            );
    void some_function(std::string incomingMessage);
};

///////////////////ConnectionHandler.cpp
#include "cnn.h"
#include "Broker.h"
ConnectionHandler::ConnectionHandler(
//...
        Broker<int,int>& broker, messageReceiveCallback callback
        //...
        ) :
        receiveCallBack(callback), theBroker(broker) {

}

void ConnectionHandler::some_function(std::string incomingMessage) {
    CALL_MEMBER_FN(theBroker, receiveCallBack)(shared_from_this(),incomingMessage);
}
```

- As you can see one of the `ConnectionHandler` responsibilities is to deliver the incoming messages to the `Broker` by calling the broker's call back function(look at `ConnectionHandler::some_function`).
- The only way I know to call the callback function is to define a macro `CALL_MEMBER_FN` and pass the object,member function, and argument(s) like what you saw above.
- so far seems so good!

**BUT**

The problem is that, I *just* have recently *templetized* the `Broker` . Consequently, I was forced to provide *specific*(and useless) template arguments when passing the Broker class and callback information to `ConnectionHandler`. Do you see the problem? In fact while trying to `generalize` the `Broker`, I had to `specialize` the `ConnectionHandler` ! ConnectionHandler, by its own, has got no other business with Broker template arguments.

I think If you could help me with a better suggestion for passing the function pointer to the ConnectionHandler without involving the Broker template arguments, it will make my day :)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the two options are:

1. Derive the `Broker` template from a non-template base class that acts as an interface and defines the core functions that are used by the `ConnectionHandler` as virtual functions. The `Broker` template would then override those functions. The `ConnectionHandler` would work with pointers to the new base class only (no more template arguments in the `ConnectionHandler` implementation). Drawback: *Possibly* slower performance as the calls into the `Broker` would have to go through the one extra level of dereferencing.
2. Make the `ConnectionHandler` a template as well, taking the same parameters as `Broker`. Drawback: You will need a separate instance of `ConnectionHandler` for every combination of template arguments. From the code you showed, this wouldn't be a problem, though.

   Here is a brief code example that shows how the template arguments for `ConnectionHandler` could be derived at initialization time. It's done by implementing a function template `make_connectionhandler`, which takes a broker (of any type) as argument and then creates the `ConnectionHandler` with template arguments that match those of the `Broker`. This works because *function templates* (as opposed to class templates) can deduce their template parameters from the arguments they are given:

   ```
   /* Using C++11 syntax. */
   #include <iostream>

   template <typename T>
   struct Broker
   {
     using type = T;

     void act(type token) const
     {
       std::cout << token << std::endl;
     }
   };

   template <typename BrokerType>
   struct ConnectionHandler
   {

     ConnectionHandler(const BrokerType &broker)
       : broker_(broker)
     { };

     void handle_request(typename BrokerType::type token)
     {
       broker_.act(token);
     }

   private:
     const BrokerType &broker_;
   };


   template <typename BrokerType>
   ConnectionHandler<BrokerType> make_connectionhandler(const BrokerType &broker)
   { return { broker }; }
   ```

   Here is a `main` program that shows how the `make_connectionhandler` function can be used:

   ```
   int main()
   {
     Broker<int> broker;

     auto handler = make_connectionhandler(broker);

     handler.handle_request(42);

     return 0;
   }
   ```

   I've used C++11 syntax above. In C++03, you can't use `auto`, which unfortunately means that in the declaration of `handler` above, the template arguments will still appear:

   ```
   ConnectionHandler<Brokern<int> > handler = make_connectionhandler(broker);
   ```

   Unfortunately, there is not much you can do to avoid this completely in C++03.

Comment: jogojapan, thank you for your suggestions. options-1: seems a very nice solution. I will just try it and get back to you.    option-2: over my dead body :)  coz ConnectionHandler is going to be part of my core library. So is the Broker! that is why I am generalizing it so that people can create subclasses&provide definition for its virtual functions. if there was a way to automatically specify argument types for a templatized ConnectionHandler at the same time when i create a Broker subclass, then this option would also answer my needs.

Comment: Oh, so you would accept making the `ConnectionHandler` a template, if only the template arguments would be automatically deduced at initialization time? That can be done...

Comment: no, I can't use  C++11. BTW, I just used your first option and it is nicely working. and about your second comment, ConnectionHandler is not a member of Broker. How can this be done? otherwise, I appreciate if you could send me an example. Thanks again.

Comment: @rahman I've added some code to explain what I mean. Unfortunately, in C++03 it's not quite as nice as in C++11.